# Without for loop generate t distribution data

Tags: r

I want to generate t distribution data using quantile function with df (degrees of freedom) vector and probability vector p.

```
p <- c(0.01, 0.001, 0.0001)
dof <- c(seq(1, 5, by = 1))
```

I can use for loop as below to do the job.

```
for (i in dof) {(qt(1-p, df=i))}
```

Without for loop, i can use lapply function but it gives output as a list.

```
val <- lapply(dof, function(d) qt(1-p, df=d))
```

How can I avoid for loop and get the output as data.frame.

Edit:

Using sapply result is correct but transpose form:

```
val <- sapply(dof, function(d) qt(1-p, df=d))
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
[1,]   31.82052  6.964557  4.540703  3.746947 3.364930
[2,]  318.30884 22.327125 10.214532  7.173182 5.893430
[3,] 3183.09876 70.700071 22.203742 13.033672 9.677566
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a loop and why are you trying to get a data.frame when all your values are numeric?

Comment: So that I can do vector manipulation. the actual dataset is quite large.

Comment: A list is a vector, same as a matrix. Manuipulating a data.frame, is not so efficient when it comes to large data sets. Regarding your edit, just wrap it into `t`.

Comment: Thakns for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this work?

```
val <- sapply(dof, function(d) qt(1-p, df=d))
```

Comment: see my edit in the question. Can the out be in the transpose form? I can transpose manually but I want to avoid it since actual data set is quite large.